# How many trials are needed to confidently determine a phenomenon's probability?

Tags: probability

I want to calculate the probability of a phenomenon (success when something occurs, and failure when it doesn't occur). Let's take flipping of a coin, for simplicity (but the phenomenon is more related to fluids and its effects, though).

So I can calculate the probability (using the frequentist approach) as number of successes divided by number of total trials.

But how do I decide the number of trials, so that it reflects the true probability. I can repeat the experiment to find out the probability maybe 50, 70 or even 100 times, but how can I be certain that the number of trials is enough, because trying it out infinite times is not possible in reality.

I hope my question is clear. Please help...

Comment: If you ever see polls on the TV news with the term "margin of error," that's the number you are looking for.

Comment: If you have independent trials, number of successes have a binomial distribution bin(n,p) where $0<p<1$.  So you must look up confidence interval for $p$, for instance here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Comment: Any answer you get to this question is going to be a lie, or they will add some assumptions and be less of a lie but still a lie.

Comment: @ABC That's not true. There's a difference between an estimate and a lie. :)

Comment: More.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: thanks for the help, i guess i can use the clopper-pearson interval for my problem.